# Distance between two zip codes in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best way to find out if a address/postalcode is within 60 miles of an address in Snowflake? In Google BigQuery there is the `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` that allows you to this.

Answer (score 1):

The Snowflake Marketplace has multiple data sets available for geocoding such as [Worldwide Address Data](https://app.snowflake.com/marketplace/listing/GZSNZ7F5UT?search=geocoding). After geocoding your addresses, you can use Snowflake geospatial function [ST_DISTANCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_distance.html) to calculate distances.

Answer (score 1):

It would help a lot if you can provide us a new question with a sample query that you run in BQ. That would help us make sure that we are getting what you want, and we would be able to test it.

In the meantime, let me give you a query with the Worldwide Address Data dataset that Dave suggests:

```sql
select st_distance(st_point(lon, lat), xy), postcode
from worldwide_address_data.address.openaddress
join data
where country='us'
and postcode != ''
and lon between -180 and 180
and lat between -90 and 90
and postcode like '95%'
and length(postcode)>=51
order by 1 desc
limit 100
```

This could/needs to be optimized, but we can get there as you give us more specifics.

[image]